# Can I check luggage for my wife if I have her boarding pass?

Tags: luggage, singapore

My wife and I are on our honeymoon in Malaysia. On our way out of the country, we would go to Istanbul. We had planned the following trip:

- 29 August evening: Kuala Lumpur --> Singapore
- 30 August early morning: Singapore --> Istanbul

She has a Moroccan passport, so she is not allowed to leave the security area of the Singapore airport without a Singapore visa. The plan was to check our luggage in Kuala Lumpur and then collect it in Istanbul.

But there was an error on Expedia, and the planned Kuala Lumpur --> Singapore trip that we bought actually left on 19 August, so we need to buy a new ticket to Singapore (which is not that expensive).

The problem is, because the new ticket to Singapore will be "disconnected" from our Singapore-Istanbul ticket, we will have to re-check our luggage once we are in Singapore. She will not be allowed to go to the luggage drop-off zone because she has a Moroccan passport with no Singapore visa. I have a Canadian passport. I can collect the luggage for her after passing Singapore's passport control, but can I check in her bags for her too if I have her boarding pass?

Comment: Which airline are you flying to Istanbul on? I suggest contacting them first.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: if your original plan was to travel on a single ticket, and you've now missed the first KUL-SIN flight on 19 Aug, are you sure you still have a flight from SIN to IST?  It has likely been cancelled if you no-showed to the first leg.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions in comments. Put on hold for now.